# How to formalize that $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0 \implies$ $g$ "grows faster" than $f$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, definition, intuition

I understand that $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$ implies that, for sufficiently large values of $x$, $f(x)<g(x)$, as a direct consequence of the definition of limit to $\infty$.

But how can the idea that $g$ **grows faster** than $f$ be formalized? Is it somehow related to the derivatives of the functions?

Comment: Why not use the limit as the definition? Derivatives require differentiability, but the concept itself should apply whether the function is differentiable or not.

Comment: Not just $f(x)<g(x)$ for large values of $x$ but $f(x)<\varepsilon g(x)$ for every $\varepsilon$ (and for large values of $x$), this means that $f$ can be as smaller as we want with respect to $g$, or equivalently, $g(x)$ can be as bigger as we want with respect to $f(x)$, that is (In my opinion) the origin of the concept of "grows faster".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Landau's symbols
$$o(\cdot),\ \sim,\ \asymp$$
the limit is *precisely* the definition.
More specifically:
$$\begin{align}
f = o(g) &\iff \lim_{x \to \alpha}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0\\
f \sim_\alpha g &\iff \lim_{x \to \alpha}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1 \iff f(x) = g(x) + o(g(x))\\
f \asymp_\alpha &\iff \lim_{x \to \alpha}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = l \in \mathbb R,\mbox{ with }l \neq 0
\end{align}$$

Note that when using Landau's $o(\cdot)$, $\alpha$ is implicit: therefore you'll have to specify it in order to avoid confusion.

Landau's little $o$ is very useful as it offers a neat notation that has nice properties:
$$\begin{align}
f\cdot o(g) &= o(f\cdot g)\\
k\cdot o(f) &= o(k\cdot f) = o(f),\quad\mbox{with }k \in \mathbb R \backslash \{0\}\\
o(o(f)) &= o(f)\\
o(f + o(f)) &= o(f)
\end{align}$$
You can prove all of them (and there are a few more) with the definition of $o(\cdot)$. As you can imagine, it would be very tedious to write all of them in their limit form. This is why this concise notation is often preferred.

Comment: As far as I understand the question is "How to formalize the concept '$f$ grows faster that $g$'?". I don't see the answer to this question in your answer.

Comment: @GitGud: One way to formalize the concept is with Landau's symbol little-o. That's what I intended.

Comment: The definition is the limit, but the answer explains why is it more convenient to use little-o.

Comment: @rubik thanks for this suggestion.